# context is not defined

Tags: jquery-animate, gsap

I am trying to draw a picture into a div to be able to make the drag effect later. It seems that the function that has to draw the image is not working right.  Maybe someone has a hint why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>canvas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/utils/Draggable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;">

     <div id="imagen" class="mover"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here the js code..

```
context.getContext("2d");
var movibles = $(".mover");
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");


make_base();

function make_base()
{
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'img/image.jpg';
  base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
  }
}

Draggable.create("movibles" , {
   type:"y",
   bounds: document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
   throwProps:true,
   onClick: function() {
       console.log("clicked");
   },
   onDragEnd:function() {
       console.log("drag ended");
   }

});
```

Much appreciated..

Comment: Seems like you are using context without defining it. You need something like var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); See this link for example: 

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#Examples)

Comment: And also the getContext(...) only works on a canvas element and not on the div.